# Which is faster in execution time : hql or standard sql?

Tags: hibernate, hql

Which of these two snippets is the fastest in response :

```
String hql = "from Menu where groupeMenu = :gm";
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("gm" , criteres.get("gmnu_code"));
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Menu> listMenu = (List<Menu>) query.list();
```

or :

```
String sql = "select menu_id from menu where gmnu_code = :gm";
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("gm" , criteres.get("gmnu_code"));
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Menu> listMenu = (List<Menu>) query.list();
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out? There will, in practice, most likely not be a signficant difference.

Comment: but when the table will contain more rows will there be difference ?

Comment: It doesn't meter how much columns is present in DB, in current case the only difference is that in first case your HQL will be parsed and transformed to native SQL, and it will made for constant time and as @Jesper told, mostly profit in second case will be very small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the underlying database only accept sql requests, and you can even ask spring to show the generated query. The difference is jsut that when you use hql, you rely on spring to parse the recordset to give you objects, while when you use raw SQL, you must say how to process the recordset.

That means that from a database point of view there will be no difference at all (for such a simple query, the hql will be translated in the expample sql). And on client it depends whether you can produce more optimized code that what spring produces. The good question is just whether it is worth it, because in the end you get more code to produce test and maintain. A rule of thumb is that unless you have performance problems in a specific query, hql is the best way, and raw SQL should only be used from specific use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the second query executing won't work with the code you posted. There is no logic to map SQL results to Menu entity.

In common case pure SQL is faster especially in case of complex queries. Hibernate anyway generates SQL from the entities and sometimes the generated queries could be really complex (especially if you have eager relations).

But...

If you retrieve IDs only you get into N+1 queries problem. So it first gets all ids and then for each id retrieves all the fields for the entity. In this case pure SQL is slower because of N+1 real DB queries instead of one big query generated by hibernate.

So you can use JDBC Template to run pure SQL and add row mapper to map the results to entities. But if you need something more than simple reading (e.g. you need to update all the entities) then using HQL seems more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

There is one difference between sql ond hql in your example. Via sql you can fetch only columns that you are really need.

While hql is translated to sql, all columns with **EAGER** fetch type will be retrieved. HQL itself doesn't allow you to specify the columns.